# Determining location of the automatic page breaks in OpenXML worksheet

Tags: c#, vb.net, openxml, closedxml

I am working on a program that generates an output document in Excel xlsx format. I wrote the functionality and was getting the expected output/result using Excel Interop, originally, but it was taking quite awhile to complete a single output so I am trying to duplicate the same functionality using OpenXML (currently using the ClosedXML library to simplify the conversion from the Excel Interop but I'm open to any other libraries or methods...)

The basic process is opening the template file (which has the initial print area [A1:M27] and print settings are already set up and defined) and then populating the template with the data. The first row of data starts in cell A11 with additional rows are inserted below this, as needed. (There is additional stuff on the template that is below this table of data, so the last row that is inserted is not the bottom of the actual print area.)

After inserting the second row of data, I have a function that will check if the value of the given cell and the value of the cell located immediately above it are the same. If so, then it checks to make sure that there aren't any page breaks located there before merging them.

Here's that section of relevant code:

```
        For Each HBreak In outputSheet.PageSetup.RowBreaks
            If HBreak = FirstCell.CellAbove.WorksheetRow.RowNumber Then Exit Sub
        Next HBreak
```

When I generate the output, however, it still ends up merging cells across page breaks. I stepped through the code and found that `outputSheet.PageSetup.RowBreaks` is ***always*** empty... yet when I open the output file in Excel, there will be an automatic page break going right through the middle of the cells it merged.

I did a test and inserted a horizontal page break right where the data rows are inserted into the template to see if it would correctly detect *manually-placed* page breaks and *then* the check for a page break worked as intended... but only for the manually inserted break.

So it seems my issue is with the page break locations that are determined **automatically** based on the existing printing and page setup.

Is it possible to determine where the ***automatic*** page breaks are with OpenXML (or ***anything*** *other than* Excel Interop)?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit/Update**: 
I managed to come up with a way to work-around this for the current situation, but it doesn't work very well after inserting the first initial page break.

I took the template and incrementally increased the row height until I found the point where increasing any row heights by one additional point caused the automatic page-break to shift. I wrote a function that summed the row heights before that pagebreak, giving me a value of `943`.

Then, before checking for any page breaks, I call this procedure:

```
Private Sub InsertPageBreaks(outputSheet As IXLWorksheet)
    Dim TotalHeight As Double = 0
    Dim PageBreakHeight As Double = 943.5      ' Worksheet/Page Layout-specific value

    ' Reset/clear all of the horizontal row breaks
    outputSheet.PageSetup.RowBreaks.Clear()

    For x = 1 To (outputSheet.LastRowUsed(True).RowNumber)

        TotalHeight += outputSheet.Row(x).Height

        If TotalHeight > PageBreakHeight Then
            ' If the total height exceeds the page break point, insert a new
            '   new page break at this point and then reset TotalHeight
            outputSheet.PageSetup.AddHorizontalPageBreak(x - 1)
            TotalHeight = 0
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

The downside is that I will need to use a variation of this procedure for each different output template I use because of the differences in page layouts, scaling, page orientation, etc., so it isn't a very practical solution beyond this one specific application. Additionally, there appears to be a bit of "drift" that occurs after the first page break is inserted, and the pagebreaks no longer fit where Excel's automatic pagebreaks are inserted by the third page.

So... still looking for a better solution.